# How to convert grouped/binned dataframe to numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I was wondering how I would be able to convert my binned dataframe to a binned numpy array that I can use in sklearn's PCA.

Here's my code so far (x is my original unbinned dataframe):

```
bins=(2,6,10,14,20,26,32,38,44,50,56,62,68,74,80,86,92,98)
binned_data = x.groupby(pd.cut(x.Weight, bins))
```

I want to convert binned_data to a numpy array. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

When I try binned_data.values, I receive this error:

```
AttributeError: Cannot access attribute 'values' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method
```

Comment: would it be `binned_data.values`?

Comment: No, I have tried that and received this: AttributeError: Cannot access attribute 'values' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

Comment: Please add a short description of `x` or some code to generate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply some kind of aggregation to the GroupBy object to return a DataFrame.  Once you have that, you can use `.values` to extract the numpy arrary.

For example, if you wanted the sum or count of the data in each bin you could do:

```
binned_data.sum().values
binned_data.size().values
```

Edit:
My code wasn't exactly right, because the column (Weight) and the index will have the same name.  It can be fixed by renaming the index, as below:

```
binned_data = x.groupby(pd.cut(x.Weight, bins)).sum()
binned_data.index.name = 'Weight_Bin'
binned_data.reset_index().values
```

Comment: Input: data = binned_data.sum().reset_index().values and then I got the Output: ValueError: cannot insert Weight, already exists. What do you think is causing this?